# Привязка данных к list - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Я получаю температурные показатели с COM-порта и теперь необходимо использовать их в температурном графике реального времени.

Примерно я хочу сделать вот так:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TemperatureGraph tempGraph = new TemperatureGraph(new List<int> { },new List<double> { });
        Panelchart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(tempGraph.DateTimeList,tempGraph.TemperatureList);
    }
}
public class TemperatureGraph
{
    private List<int> DateTime;
    private List<double> Temperature;
    public List<int> DateTimeList { get { return DateTime; } }
    public List<double> TemperatureList { get { return Temperature; } }
    public TemperatureGraph(List<int> DateTime,List<double> Temperature)
    {
        this.DateTime = DateTime;
        this.Temperature = Temperature;
    }
}
```

Я получаю данные в этих фрагментах кода:

```
 private void Response(byte[] msg)
    {
        Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            //Response Collect Data
            for (int i = 0; i < msg.Length; i++)
                responsecollect.Add(msg[i]);
            // Function 3 response
            if (responsecollect.Count == responseFunc3total)
            {
                byte[] responseFunc3 = responsecollect.ToArray();
                //Function Code Check
                if (responseFunc3[1] == 3)
                {
                    //CRC Error Check
                    if (CRCResponseCheck(responseFunc3))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Request_Collect.Count; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < General_Collect.Count; j++)
                                if (Request_Collect[i].Adress_MB == General_Collect[j].Adress_MB)
                                {
                                    Int16 value = 0;
                                    // Рассшифровка
                                    if (Request_Collect[i].Byte_Count == 2)
                                    {
                                        //Data Hi and Registers1 from Index3
                                        value = responseFunc3[2 * i + 3];
                                        //Move to Hi
                                        value <<= 8;
                                        //Data Lo and Registers1 from Index4
                                        value += responseFunc3[2 * i + 4];
                                        if (Request_Collect[i].Adress_MB == 0x0002)
                                            richTextBox111.Text += value * Math.Pow(10, -1) +  "\n";
                                    else 
                                       richTextBox1111.Text = value * Math.Pow(10, -1) + "     " + "\n";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    if (Request_Collect[i].Byte_Count == 4)
                                    {
                                        richTextBox1111.Text += Request_Collect[i].Appointment + " (" + Request_Collect[i].Name_OWEN + ")" + " = " +
                                        BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { responseFunc3[6],
                                            responseFunc3[5], responseFunc3[4], responseFunc3[3] }, 0) + "\n";
                                    }
                                    /// char
```

`Value` - значения температуры которые я получаю и я хочу поставить `Value` вместо:

```
,new List<double> { });
```

Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Меня это пугает `Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate` очень. Нужен рефокторинг, разбейте эти матрешки в серию вызываемых методов, будет проще понять и разобраться что к чему.

Comment: Вопрос такой: как привязать данных которые я получаю к ,new List<double> { }); ???

Comment: Да, TemperatureGraph tempGraph = new TemperatureGraph(new List<int> { },new List<double> { }); // тут вместо первого параметра написать List<int> с нужными датами, а второй параметр это List<double> с нужной температурой.

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю что вам необходимо использовать фифо
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO

Ищите информацию о Queue в шарпе. Именно это и нужно эсли это список элементов изменяющийся в реальном времени. 
Это первое.

Второе, создайте простой метод который работает с чартом и заполняйте его при каждом изменении фифо. Если это первая прорисовка - тогда все точки. Если это не первая прорисовка -- тогда только удаляешь первую точку и добавляешь последнюю.

Этот метод подпиши на ивент изменения Queue.